# round numbers in js

Tags: javascript

I would like to round `45.19202405202648` to 3 decimal places.

I tried :

```
n.toFixed(3);
```

also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

```
Math.round10(n, -3);
myNamespace.round(n, 3);
```

and

```
Math.round(n * 1000 + Number.EPSILON ) / 1000;
```

but these solutions returns `45.19199999999999` insted of `45.192`

**EDIT :** Real question is if I do `65.19202405202648.toFixed(3) - 20` I get `45.19199999999999`

Thanks for your help

Comment: you tried and you got a result, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Spoiler alert https://jsfiddle.net/4yb4o2fb/

Comment: Show us the code using `toFixed`. `Number((45.19202405202648).toFixed(3))`, for instance, gives `45.192` (as a number; if you just need the string, ditch the `Number(...)` wrapper).

Comment: If you round a `number` to a `number` it'll round to the nearest approximation based on normal floating point precision. that means that if you then express it as a string, it may be off. a bit. Seems you want to format it for display instead: `number.toLocaleString('en', {maximumSignificantDigits : 3})` shoould help.

Comment: I have added some demos in OP. Please update it to show where you are having issues.Thanks!

Comment: I undersatand but if i do `65.19202405202648.toFixed(3) - 20 ` I get `45.19199999999999`

Comment: Check out my answer, you need to round first, then use toFixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your Arithmetical coprocessor is buggy. Try a different computer.

Comment: Sounds like you need more megapixels

Answer (score 0):

x - number to be rounded; n - number of decimals;

```
    function roundPlus(x, n) {
        if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(n)) return false;
        var m = Math.pow(10, n);
        return Math.round(x * m) / m;
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let num = 45.19202405202648;
console.log(num.toFixed(3));
```

Answer (score -1):

So it sounds like you've got 2 things going on here. First is the rounding part, which appears to be working as expected. The second issue is just that floating point numbers don't always map well to nice easy to read strings. So, to convert it to a nice string, you can use:

`var roundedNum = Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000;
var displayString = roundedNum.toFixed(3)`

You need to both round and use `.toFixed` to get the expected result.

Answer (score -2):

There is a function in javascript called toFixed(). This will return a number with a fixed amount of decimal places. This WILL round 90% of the time but sometimes it does not round perfectly. There is no way to round perfectly without external libraries. For example you would do this:

```
n.toFixed(3);
```

I see you have tried this already, it should work. Try and run it again or in a controlled environment.